# How to find command TexMaker used

Tags: texmaker

As I'm still VERY new to Tex I have been using TexMaker (niavely) to generate my pdf's.  I have a doc I have been working on for some time that someone else wants to manually generate with my tex files on a remote computer.  They asked me what command I used to created the document.  How do I find the command that TexMaker would run if I was just to use command line options (and not TexMaker)?  I looked in the log file that is generated but nothing really jumped out at me.

Comment: You'll probably find the exact command-line options passed under [TeXMaker's Quick Build settings](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/pics/quickbuild.png), or... elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all the details of commands used in `Options --> Configure Texmaker`. For `pdflatex`, I have highlighted the command. Please note that `%.tex` refers to your file name that is currently open in texmaker.

[image]

These are the default settings. You may also have a look at the `Quick Build window`.

Comment: Exactly what command is used depends of course on which tool is chosen from the Tools menu (or which shortcut is pressed). If Quick Build (F1) is used, a combination of the tools listed in the above screenshot may be used, though I guess pdfLaTeX is default(?).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes you are right. But without any knowledge of OP's settings we are blind. :)

Comment: Yeah, I sort of meant it as additional information to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LaTeX (and not TeX) you probable are using `pdflatex` to generate your PDF (`latex` will generate a DVI file), e.g.

```
$ pdflatex your_doc.tex
```

TexMaker probable use some flags as `-interaction nonstopmode`. For information about the this and others flags

```
$ man pdflatex
```

If the remote machine have PERL installed I suggest that you use `latexmk` since it will compile your document the number of times it need to properly generate the PDF (cross-reference need that the document be compiled at least two times). E.g.,

```
$ latexmk -pdf your_doc.tex
```